# How to share local library project across different projects in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, android-studio

I recently changed my IDE for Android from Eclipse to AndroidStudio and have a question here. 
Let's say I have two Android app project, app1 and app2. When using Eclipse, the both uses the same library project, androidlib. So when i change the code in androidlib, it takes effects in both app1 and app2. The directory structure looks like this:

```
workspace/
    app1/
    app2/
    androidlib/
```

But when I import the project app1 and app2 to AndroidStudio, then both app projects have a copy of the androidlib and put in there own directory. Now the directory structure looks like this:

```
AndroidStudioProjects/
    app1/
        app1/
        androidlib/
    app2/
        app2/
        androidlib/
```

The result is, if I change the code in androidlib in one project(say, in app1/androidlib), it only affect the project containing it(app1) and not the other one(app2).

How can I share the same androidlib project across the two projects(app1 and app2)?